# Curl 0f a function which is zero at boundary

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So, I've been told that for  $\vec{f}=\vec{f}(x,y)$ defined on $\Omega$ if $\vec{f}(x,y)=\vec{0}$ for $(x,y)\in\partial\Omega \Rightarrow\operatorname{curl}(\vec{f})=\vec{0}$.

Is this identity true? How would I prove it?

Comment: Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @DanielRust I thought it was related to Stokes' Theorem, but Stokes' theorem establishes a relation between a line integral and a surface integral, so if the line integral is zero, it doesn't mean the integral of the surface integral (the curl) is zero.

Comment: Unless there are more constraints, this is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nonsense, assuming you're on a fixed region $\Omega$. Take $$\vec f = \big((x^2+y^2-1),0\big),$$
with $\Omega = \{x^2+y^2\le 1\}$. You can modify the vector field in zillions of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Stokes' Theorems says $\iint_\Omega (\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=\int_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{t}\,ds$ where $\Omega$ is the surface and ${\partial\Omega}$ is the bounding curve. If $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{0}$ on $C$, then $\iint_{\Omega} (\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=\mathbf{0}$.

Are you sure the problem is formulated correctly? I have seen this problem in several texts before but they ask to show $\iint_{\Omega} (\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=\mathbf{0}$, which is just a straightforward application of Stokes' Theorem.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck, because the last statement doesn't mean the curl is zero, just that the surface integral of the curl is zero.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly?